# JavaFx : Event Filter on Tab (Tab Pane)

Tags: java, events, javafx, tabs

I'm working on Tab Pane on JavaFx, my problem is that i can't handle any KeyEvent inside the tab, such as F5 press or any key on the keyboard, also the function is working on any element inside the Tab like `TextField`, my goal is to handle any event inside the Tab not elements.

This is my code that i tested it

```
tab.getContent().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Filtering out event " + event.getCode());
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try adding evnt filter to content : tab.getContent().addEventFilter(...);

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to add the 'tab.getContent()' on the question, actually it's right now, and i added the 'tab.getContent()' and it's not working too

Comment: Then you should provide an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from [another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834997/cannot-listen-to-keyevent-in-javafx), layouts (TabPane in your case) do not respond to KeyEvents. So, the solution suggested and also worked for that post is adding the event filter to the scene. If you don't prefer doing that, set TabPane focusable and try your way again.